# Rust mplayer stdin/stdout

Tags: rust

пишу враппер для mplayer. почему не работает write/read? не могу не читать stdout, не писать в stdin

```
use tokio::io::{AsyncBufReadExt, AsyncWriteExt};

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    let filename = "/home/user/Intro.mp3";
    let volume: i32 = 30;

    let mut mplayer = match tokio::process::Command::new("mplayer")
        .arg("-slave")
        .arg("-idle")
        .arg("-noautosub")
        .arg("-noconsolecontrols")
        .arg("-nolirc")
        .arg("-really-quiet")
        .args(&["-softvol", "-volume", &volume.to_string()])
        .args(&["-vc", "null"])
        .args(&["-vo", "null"])
        .args(&["-ao", "alsa:device=plughw=1.0"])
        .arg("")
        .stdout(std::process::Stdio::piped())
        .stdin(std::process::Stdio::piped())
        .spawn()
    {
        Ok(p) => p,
        Err(e) => {
            println!("Can't mplayer: {}", e);
            return;
        }
    };

    let child_in = mplayer.stdin.as_mut().unwrap();
    let mut child_out = tokio::io::BufReader::new(mplayer.stdout.as_mut().unwrap());

    let mut interval_second = tokio::time::interval(std::time::Duration::from_secs(1));

    let cmd = format!("loadfile {}\n", filename);
    if let Err(e) = child_in.write_all(cmd.as_bytes()).await {
        println!("mplayer error: {}", e);
    }
    
    if let Err(e) = child_in.flush().await {
        println!("FLUSH: {}", e);
    }

    let mut line = String::new();

    loop {
        tokio::select! {
            _ = child_out.read_line(&mut line) => {
                println!("line:{}", line);
                if line.is_empty() {
                        println!("MPlayer: break");
                        break;
                    }
                }
            _ = interval_second.tick() => {
                println!("tick");
            }
        }
    }
    println!("finish");
}
```

Answer (score -1):

может кому пригодится:

```
use tokio::io::{AsyncBufReadExt, AsyncWriteExt};

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    let filename = "/home/user/Intro.mp3";
    let volume: i32 = 30;

    let mut mplayer = match tokio::process::Command::new("mplayer")
        .arg("-slave")
        .arg("-idle")
        .arg("-noautosub")
        .arg("-noconsolecontrols")
        .arg("-nolirc")
        .arg("-quiet")
        .args(&["-softvol", "-volume", &volume.to_string()])
        .args(&["-vc", "null"])
        .args(&["-vo", "null"])
        .args(&["-ao", "alsa:device=plughw=1.0"])
        .stdout(std::process::Stdio::piped())
        .stdin(std::process::Stdio::piped())
        .spawn()
    {
        Ok(p) => p,
        Err(e) => {
            println!("Can't mplayer: {}", e);
            return;
        }
    };

    let child_in = mplayer.stdin.as_mut().unwrap();
    let mut child_out = tokio::io::BufReader::new(mplayer.stdout.as_mut().unwrap());

    let mut interval_second = tokio::time::interval(std::time::Duration::from_secs(1));

    let cmd = format!("loadfile {}\n", filename);
    if let Err(e) = child_in.write_all(cmd.as_bytes()).await {
        println!("mplayer error: {}", e);
    }
    
    if let Err(e) = child_in.flush().await {
        println!("FLUSH: {}", e);
    }

    let mut line = String::new();

    loop {
        tokio::select! {
            _ = child_out.read_line(&mut line) => {
                if line == "\n" {
                        println!("MPlayer: break");
                        break;
                    }
                }
            _ = interval_second.tick() => {
                println!("tick");
            }
        }
    }

    let _ = mplayer.kill();
    println!("finish");
}
```